# Adding System.Configuration to a C# console application

Tags: c#

I am trying to access System.Configuration in a console app in the Microsoft Visual Studio. Im a newbie when it comes to microsoft development.  I know I need to add a reference. However its not obvious when I click add reference on where I would find the dll.
[image]

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried looking in NuGet package manager, it will not be in the projects section,. that is form your own projects

Comment: I don't know why but you are missing 2 menus in that window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Reference allows you to add a local reference, so a project ion that solution.

you will need to look at NuGet package manager for getting 3rd party or Microsoft libraries.
 you can find this in the same context menu as the add reference item however it will say, `Manage NuGet Packages`

Comment: I believe the NuGet package to search for is [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager)